# CentOS7 Apache - Pages are served, but base url serves internal address and is unreachable

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtualhost, centos7

I have a somewhat puzzling problem in trying to setup a website. I have a WordPress install on Centos7 running Apache.

This webserver is NAT'ed behind a firewall, so it has an internal address, but all public address http requests are forwarded to it.

Whenever I go to the IP or the website itself it gives me a "This site can't be reached" error in chrome and gives me "http://[internal address]/ is unreachable", meaning it is somehow mapping to the internal address.

However, if I navigate to site.com/index.html I can see the index file I put in my apache web root. Similarly, any specific pages serve up correctly and are fine.

This leads me to believe it's not a networking issues but something with my conf files that is weird. Here is the vhost file:

`<VirtualHost 8.8.8.8>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        ServerName google.com
</VirtualHost>`

(replacing 8.8.8.8 with my public IP, and google with my DNS name)

Could this be an issue with some Wordpress permissions? I verified apache doc root is owned by apache:apache, mariadb database permissions seem to work, the site pulls up fine again internally but not externally.

Would appreciate any help or pointers, thanks!

Comment: My guess is your virtual host is not matched when not accessed by the `ServerName`. [Then Apache serves](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#page-header) the default site / first configured vhost. You can verify that by adding `8.8.8.8 google.com` to your `/etc/hosts` (mutatis mutandis). If the site can be reached by http://google.com therefore you know what the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't it. editing hosts is basically the same as just navigating the site's IP over http, neither of which work for the plain site, but type in 8.8.8.8/index.php and that page comes up.

Comment: One interesting thing to note is that when I am on a computer on the LAN it resolves correctly because I can access the internal address. But it's likely not networking as I can access 8.8.8.8/page externally, just 8.8.8.8 seems to resolve to internal NAT'ed address and that is not accessible externally.

Comment: Apache matches vhosts by sent `HOST` header. If you access the site by an IP address, default vhost will be served instead.

Comment: Regardless of if I access the site by IP or hostname, it doesn't show up unless I navigate to a page, otherwise it gives me the above "server cannot be reached error" and it shows the internal IP.